# Problem while calling system function in arm assembly

Tags: android, assembly, arm

In bluestacks Android emulator, in some arm app, some system function, have a bad prolog. Instead of `STMFD {r0, r1, r2, lr}`, there is a `SWI 2BF4E`, yes `SWI` is for system calls in ARM but `2BF4E` is not a syscall number. When I call this specific bad prolog functions from the JNI source code of the app in android studio, the call is successful with no crashes, but when I try to call the same functions while the app running, from injected code, it just keeps crashing, the JNI code execute the same system call prolog I did and not crash.

- I made sure the offsets were correct
- the page was RWXP, so no problem with Executions violations exceptions
- tried writing the memory and setting the right prolog, from the original executable file then calling it, and still crashing

This does not happen with `mmap`, it has normal prolog and when I call it, it works as expected without crashes.

Comment: Could this be a thumb function?  It really does seem strange.

Comment: not, is just the prolog bad becouse, the body is normal arm no thumb, and i even tryed to convert it to thumb code, and didnt look like thumb code

Answer (score 1):

i solved it when i realized that in asm function body there was absolute addresses then i tried to make **my asm look like position independent code**, about the prolog, this is custom, emulator uses this specials while emulating arm in x86 in libhoudini.so(not sure).